# React useHook is causing my API backend to go into an endless loop

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework-core, react-hooks, react-table

I have an issue I can't figure out.

I am using React on my front end and .NetCore 3.1 Entity Framework as my backend.

In one of my React components, I have this button that Deletes a game from a list of games in a table.

```
<Button variant="success" onClick={() => deleteFromList(row.original)}>Publish</Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

When clicked, it executes this bit of code:

```
// when the button clicked, this calls 'updateGame' method
const deleteFromList = (e) => {
    updateGame(e, 1);
}


// updateGame submits a PUT request to the API
const updateGame = async (game, action) => {
    game.isGamePublished = action;
    await axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "api/games/" + game.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(game),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
};
```

The button works, and it is updating the correct property in the system and the database, state is updated and the table is silently updated with the proper row removed, but it sends the backend API into this endless loop which just shows this output over and over:

OutPut:

```
SELECT [d].[name]
FROM [genre] AS [d]
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command Information: Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__isGamePublished_0='?' (DbType = Boolean)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [p].[id], [p].[title], .[url], [d].[name]
FROM [game] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [genre] AS [d] ON [p].[deptId] = [d].[id]
INNER JOIN [author] AS [m] ON [p].[authorId] = [m].[id]
INNER JOIN [type] AS [t] ON [p].[typeId] = [t].[id]
LEFT JOIN [gameAuthors] AS [p0] ON [p].[id] = [p0].[gameId]
WHERE [p].[isGamePublished] = @__isGamePublished_0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ART_Game.Models.GameEntity, ART_Game, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action ART_Game.Controllers.GamesController.GetGame (ART_Game) in 10.3631ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'ART_Game.Controllers.GamesController.GetGame (ART_Game)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 18.3252ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44376/api/games/?isGamePublished=false  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint 'ART_Game.Controllers.GamesController.GetGame (ART_Game)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {action = "GetGame", controller = "Games"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ART_Game.Models.GameEntity]]] GetGame(Boolean) on controller ART_Game.Controllers.GamesController (ART_Game).
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Information: Entity Framework Core 3.1.2 initialized 'ARTGamesContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
```

I did find a "fix" but it's not really a fix because it stops my React component from, well, reacting.

The state of the data in the table is managed like this:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
    gameData(false).then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    });
}, [data]);

gameData is just a simple Axios fetch component that submits a get request to my Entity Framework API:

const gameData = async isPublished) => {
   const result = await axios("api/games/", {
      params: {
        isGamePublished: isPublished
      }
   });
  return result;
};

export default gameData;
```

The "fix" is, to take out "data" in here [data] in the React.useEffect hook.

But that prevents the React component from dynamically removing the game from the table...instead the user would need to refresh the webpage in order to see the new results.

I was wondering if anyone has seen anything like this and knows how to fix it correctly?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to refetch the data only when you interact with the table. Either you can fetch the data from server or delete the item from state yourself based no row that was selected.

Below is the approach to fetch data from server.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

const fetchAndUpdate = useCallback(() => {
   gameData(false).then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    });
}, [])

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchAndUpdate()
}, []);


// when the button clicked, this calls 'updateGame' method
const deleteFromList = async (e) => {
    await updateGame(e, 1);
    fetchAndUpdate(); // fetch data and update state
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I be worried that I am getting a warning in Visual Code that says 'React Hook UseEffect is missing dependency fetchAndUpdate' ?

Comment: Since its implemented with useCallback you can add it to dependency without worry. However it alright even if you don't add it since you only want the effect to run on initial render